# Cassandra's nodetool snapshot renders node unresponsive

Tags: cassandra, snapshot

I have noticed that using `nodetool snapshot` on a Cassandra node causes heavy load (100% on two cores) for around 10-30 seconds. The snapshots are around 1GB in size. During that time connections to that node time out. How do I prevent this?

**EDIT:**

Cassandra version 2.1.1

Compression on all tables is LZ4Compressor.

Compaction strategy is STCS.

Incremental backups are off.

Compaction throughput limited to 16MB/s.

Most settings left on default.

Here a snippet of the relevant logs during a backup:

```
INFO  [CompactionExecutor:49922] 2017-08-21 00:15:16,672 CompactionTask.java:252 - Compacted 4 sstables to [/mnt/cassandra/data/system/compactions_in_progress-55080ab05d9c388690a4acb25fe1f77b/system-compactions_in_progress-ka-56311,].  447 bytes to 173 (~38% of original) in 52ms = 0.003173MB/s.  3 total partitions merged to 2.  Partition merge counts were {1:1, 2:1, }
INFO  [CompactionExecutor:49922] 2017-08-21 00:15:16,674 ColumnFamilyStore.java:856 - Enqueuing flush of compactions_in_progress: 1360 (0%) on-heap, 0 (0%) off-heap
INFO  [MemtableFlushWriter:61136] 2017-08-21 00:15:16,674 Memtable.java:324 - Writing Memtable-compactions_in_progress@399278616(170 serialized bytes, 9 ops, 0%/0% of on/off-heap limit)
INFO  [MemtableFlushWriter:61136] 2017-08-21 00:15:16,696 Memtable.java:363 - Completed flushing /mnt/cassandra/data/system/compactions_in_progress-55080ab05d9c388690a4acb25fe1f77b/system-compactions_in_progress-ka-56312-Data.db (194 bytes) for commitlog position ReplayPosition(segmentId=1482099209638, position=32331738)
INFO  [CompactionExecutor:49922] 2017-08-21 00:15:16,697 CompactionTask.java:136 - Compacting [SSTableReader(path='/mnt/cassandra/data/mycompany_social/comment_notification_preferences-61806e80d6cf11e688f0cf4dda6df27f/mycompany_social-comment_notification_preferences-ka-1799-Data.db'), SSTableReader(path='/mnt/cassandra/data/mycompany_social/comment_notification_preferences-61806e80d6cf11e688f0cf4dda6df27f/mycompany_social-comment_notification_preferences-ka-1800-Data.db'), SSTableReader(path='/mnt/cassandra/data/mycompany_social/comment_notification_preferences-61806e80d6cf11e688f0cf4dda6df27f/mycompany_social-comment_notification_preferences-ka-1801-Data.db'), SSTableReader(path='/mnt/cassandra/data/mycompany_social/comment_notification_preferences-61806e80d6cf11e688f0cf4dda6df27f/mycompany_social-comment_notification_preferences-ka-1798-Data.db')]
INFO  [CompactionExecutor:49922] 2017-08-21 00:15:22,674 ColumnFamilyStore.java:856 - Enqueuing flush of compactions_in_progress: 180 (0%) on-heap, 0 (0%) off-heap
INFO  [MemtableFlushWriter:61135] 2017-08-21 00:15:22,674 Memtable.java:324 - Writing Memtable-compactions_in_progress@542498536(0 serialized bytes, 1 ops, 0%/0% of on/off-heap limit)
INFO  [MemtableFlushWriter:61135] 2017-08-21 00:15:22,704 Memtable.java:363 - Completed flushing /mnt/cassandra/data/system/compactions_in_progress-55080ab05d9c388690a4acb25fe1f77b/system-compactions_in_progress-ka-56313-Data.db (42 bytes) for commitlog position ReplayPosition(segmentId=1482099209638, position=32335294)
INFO  [CompactionExecutor:49922] 2017-08-21 00:15:22,713 CompactionTask.java:252 - Compacted 4 sstables to [/mnt/cassandra/data/mycompany_social/comment_notification_preferences-61806e80d6cf11e688f0cf4dda6df27f/mycompany_social-comment_notification_preferences-ka-1803,].  1,671,656 bytes to 1,671,470 (~99% of original) in 6,015ms = 0.265010MB/s.  40,290 total partitions merged to 40,290.  Partition merge counts were {1:40290, }
INFO  [CompactionExecutor:49922] 2017-08-21 00:15:22,717 ColumnFamilyStore.java:856 - Enqueuing flush of compactions_in_progress: 1514 (0%) on-heap, 0 (0%) off-heap
```

Comment: Is there any additional information in the log files?

Comment: to create a snapshot, cassandra creates hard links to existing sstables. this is usually a rapid procedure and shouldn't stress the CPU in that fashion. Do some of your column families have a lot of sstables? What compaction strategy are you using? Can you rule out that the node was doing GC?

Comment: The logs mention that SSTables are being compacted and iotop shows a lot of flushing going on. Is this because the compaction doesn't happen regularly enough? I am taking the backups every 4 hours. Inbetween I can see compactions going on.

Comment: @LHWizard how much is "lot" of sstables?

Comment: @hot2use pls see updated question

Comment: I'm using STCS (size-tiered compaction strategy) in my clusters. I usually have 10 or less sstables per columnfamily. Leveled compaction strategy can generate thousands of sstables, on the other hand. Which compaction strategy are you using and could this contribute to the large amount of disk thrashing? you can use `nodetool cfstats` to check.

Comment: @LHWizard it is STCS and no table has more than 6 SSTables (after around 1h since last snapshot)